# In which case Jackson creates ShortNode when deserializing JSON with ObjectMapper.readTree?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have some code which deserializes JSON from `InputStream` via Jackson's `ObjectMapper` (basically, just like `new ObjectMapper().readTree(...)`.
I found out that it creates either `IntNode` or `LongNode` for integral numbers (depending of how big is the number), but I never saw `ShortNode`s. I need to know when they are created (if created at all), because I have some tricky logic relying on the `NumericNode.numberValue()` return type.
I did't found anything in Jackson's documentation, and Jackson's code looks not very clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken` enum contains `VALUE_NUMBER_INT` with below [documentation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.6.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonToken.java#JsonToken.0VALUE_NUMBER_INT):

> VALUE_NUMBER_INT is returned when an integer numeric token is
> encountered in value context: that is, a number that does not have
> floating point or exponent marker in it (consists only of an optional
> sign, followed by one or more digits)

There is also `VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT` token used for floating-point numbers.
Also take a look on `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer#_fromInt` method which you can find [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/f6ed9582ccf8a8889c0ae544db4ed8c3dc46ac91/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/JsonNodeDeserializer.java#L705).

```
protected final JsonNode _fromInt(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt,
        JsonNodeFactory nodeFactory) throws IOException
{
    JsonParser.NumberType nt;
    int feats = ctxt.getDeserializationFeatures();
    if ((feats & F_MASK_INT_COERCIONS) != 0) {
        if (DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_INTEGER_FOR_INTS.enabledIn(feats)) {
            nt = JsonParser.NumberType.BIG_INTEGER;
        } else if (DeserializationFeature.USE_LONG_FOR_INTS.enabledIn(feats)) {
            nt = JsonParser.NumberType.LONG;
        } else {
            nt = p.getNumberType();
        }
    } else {
        nt = p.getNumberType();
    }
    if (nt == JsonParser.NumberType.INT) {
        return nodeFactory.numberNode(p.getIntValue());
    }
    if (nt == JsonParser.NumberType.LONG) {
        return nodeFactory.numberNode(p.getLongValue());
    }
    return nodeFactory.numberNode(p.getBigIntegerValue());
}
```

Also you have to take a look on `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase#_parseNumericValue` method which you can find [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/blob/2fdd89a53a135d1fe71ee45362db7b7716913eeb/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/base/ParserBase.java#L876)

```
/**
 * Method that will parse actual numeric value out of a syntactically
 * valid number value. Type it will parse into depends on whether
 * it is a floating point number, as well as its magnitude: smallest
 * legal type (of ones available) is used for efficiency.
 *
 * @param expType Numeric type that we will immediately need, if any;
 *   mostly necessary to optimize handling of floating point numbers
 */
protected void _parseNumericValue(int expType) throws IOException
{
    // Int or float?
    if (_currToken == JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_INT) {
        int len = _intLength;
        // First: optimization for simple int
        if (len <= 9) { 
            int i = _textBuffer.contentsAsInt(_numberNegative);
            _numberInt = i;
            _numTypesValid = NR_INT;
            return;
        }
        if (len <= 18) { // definitely fits AND is easy to parse using 2 int parse calls
            long l = _textBuffer.contentsAsLong(_numberNegative);
            // Might still fit in int, need to check
            if (len == 10) {
                if (_numberNegative) {
                    if (l >= MIN_INT_L) {
                        _numberInt = (int) l;
                        _numTypesValid = NR_INT;
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (l <= MAX_INT_L) {
                        _numberInt = (int) l;
                        _numTypesValid = NR_INT;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            _numberLong = l;
            _numTypesValid = NR_LONG;
            return;
        }
        _parseSlowInt(expType);
        return;
    }
    if (_currToken == JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT) {
        _parseSlowFloat(expType);
        return;
    }
    _reportError("Current token (%s) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors", _currToken);
}
```

As you can see there is no `short` or `Short` types during deserialization. You should avoid creating logic on type of value which is created by external library. In that case is not possible to force use `Short`.

**EDIT**
And of course this is not possible because `JSON` specification does not support this. Take a look on below links for more details:

- [JSON](https://www.json.org/)
- [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-6)

Comment: It's kind of odd that the codebase has `ShortNode` and `JsonNode.isShort()` given that these can never be used during deserialization.

Comment: @Gili, I guess, it could be used by serialisation process. So user can create `ShortNode` which wraps `short` `Java` type but I can not find any good scenario where it could be preferred. Probably this class was created just to have a counterpart on Jackson side for `short`.